# How to sort list by parameter in python?

Tags: python

I have a list of employee records. Each tuple of the list represent a person's record, which includes his name, ID, and age.

For example,

emp_records = [('Karim',100, 45), ('Rahim',10, 30),('Salim', 300,60),('Abu',50,35)]

Now, I want to sort emp_records based on ID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use lambda function to pass argument by which you need to sort the records.

For example,

```
sorted_list=sorted(emp_records, key=lambda emp : emp[1])   //Here 1 means ID    
print(sorted_list)
```

You can also use the operator module. The operator module has the `itemgetter` function, which takes item as argument and sort based on the argument

For example,

```
from operator import itemgetter    
sorted_list=sorted(emp_records, key=itemgetter(1)) // Here 1 means ID    
print(sorted_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the sorted function. It accepts key as argument.
You can then use a lambda to sort on the relevant index of your tuple.

```
sorted(emp_records, key=lambda x: x[1])
```